# Google static Maps always returning 403 when a key is provided

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I always get a 403 Forbidden response if I provide an API key within the map request; without specifying it everything goes well and I can get to the map. The problem is that I have to work with an API key in order to monitor usage and per-user quota.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/demerzel3/ZUC6m/

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyDqq140S23Q_H_dmyUIFz-YwsbH_rCSFSs&size=320x140&scale=2&zoom=15&sensor=false&markers=color:0xEE6B1C|label:A|V.%20FALCONE%207%20CASALETTO%20LODIGIANO%20(LO)
```

In the example above I'm using a registered API Key configured in order to allow jsfiddle as a referer (I can attach a screenshot of the API Console if necessary).
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally sorted things out, the problem was that I was subscribing to the "Google Maps API v2" service instead of "Static Maps API".

Switching them in the API console fixed the problem.

Comment: I also had the same problem, and this was the exact fix. Google returns a 403 but with no other message as to why you got that error.

Comment: Also check to be sure you're using the right key for the specific project you're working on (I made this mistake)