# What causes "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. An internal error was found for this API project."?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is using the Static Maps API.

I have a web page with 3 img tags, each of which is a call to the static [maps API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=png&center=cv33%209ND&zoom=10&size=999x998&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:aa%7Ccv33%209ND&sensor=false&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:A%7Ce14%208js&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyA7-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_JGk), (NB of course this is not the real api key).

The 3 tags are identical, except the zoom, which is 10, 13 and 16 for the three images.

The API Key is from a project with the Static maps API enabled, and billing configured and enabled.

I have sent perhaps 60 requests in total (this is a brand new development project, so I'm just getting started).

What I'm seeing is that sometimes, all three maps are displayed. At other times one (random from the three) map fails with

> **403 "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. An internal error was found for this API project."**

So if I refresh the page 5 times, ie 15 requests, I get approx 4 failures and 11 successes.

So why is Google Maps randomly rejecting some of the requests with this 403?

Comment: link gives: "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The provided API key is invalid."

Comment: That's because I obfuscated my API key

Comment: I'm not able to replicate but can try look into it.  You can file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues under Static Maps, and be sure to provide (here or there) your numeric project id, confirm that your key you are using ends in JGk, and ensure your contact email in your project is correct. If you're not comfortable sharing your numeric project ID (it is safe to do so) then you need to provide a way I can contact you.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you exclude the `key=API_KEY` parameter?

Comment: @TylerEich without the key it works fine up until I run out of quota when I get the red X map as expected.

Comment: Do you have a demo of the problem code, like a Plunk or JSFiddle? Perhaps your issue can be replicated and more easily debugged.

Comment: By any chance, does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719319/after-months-of-100-stability-today-i-get-403-error-on-google-maps-services help you?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your API key is correct?

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits :

> The Google Static Maps API has the following usage limits:
>
> - Without an API key:
>
>   1,000 Static Maps requests per IP address per 24 hour period.
>     **50 Static Maps requests per IP address per minute. This means that if you have a single page containing more than 50 maps, the page will exceed this limit.**
>
> Additional image requests can be purchased on a per application basis at the rate currently listed in the FAQ. Additional quota is purchased through the API Console and requires the use of an API key.
>
> If a user exceeds these limits, the server will return an HTTP 403 status and display the below image to indicate that the quota has been exceeded:
>
> [image: 403 screenshot]

Seems like the 50 maps per minute could explain your random 403 errors.

If this isn't the problem, I would file a support ticket with Google Geo support since it's labelled as "an internal error".

Comment: yes I'm sure it's correct, As I said in the question, out of 15 or so GETs, a random 4 will fail, 11 will succeed. If the API key were wrong, the error would be "The provided API key is invalid.". I'm not doing 50 per minute, I'm doing 3 in a single page, then spending 2 minutes muttering "wtf" before trying again. Also, the text you quote is for no API key. I'm including an API key. And I'm not getting the quota image returned, I'm just getting a 403.

How do I file a ticket with Google Geo support?

Comment: Makes sense, figured it was worth asking the easy stuff.  Do you have a login to https://google.secure.force.com/ ?  That is how I file a ticket.

Comment: Any chance the [Static API subscription in your dev console is the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598091/google-static-maps-always-returning-403-when-a-key-is-provided)?  [Another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154608/google-static-map-api-getting-403-forbidden-when-loading-from-img-tag) says something similar.

Comment: I don't have enterprise support. This is something transient. A while ago all of my requests were succeeding. Now, they are all failing. All of this without me changing anything in the test page. My app is only subscribed to the Static Maps API, which I believe is correct. If I remove the API Key, it works of course, but then I'm subject to quota restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

> So if I refresh the page 5 times, ie 15 requests, I get approx 4 failures and 11 successes.

I think your requests exceed the limit in short time.
I'm not sure how you display the map, but I recommend you load the map serially.

Ex: using JavaScript with https://github.com/caolan/async

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html,body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="async.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadImg(params, callback) {
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?" + 
                   params + "&zoom=1&size=100x100" +
                   "&sensor=false&key={YOUR_KEY_IS_HERE}";
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = function() {
          document.body.appendChild(img);
          callback();
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
          callback(url);
        }
      }

      function loadMaps() {
        var urlList = [
          "markers=label:0|LosAngles",
          "markers=label:1|NewYork",
          "markers=label:2|SanFrancisco",
          "markers=label:3|Frorida",
          "markers=label:4|Arizona",
          "markers=label:5|Ohaio",
          "markers=label:6|Hawai",
          "markers=label:7|Texus",
          "markers=label:8|Seattle",
          "markers=label:9|Florida",
          "markers=label:A|kansas",
          "markers=label:B|utah",
          "markers=label:C|iowa",
          "markers=label:D|oregon",
          "markers=label:E|alaska",
          "markers=label:F|Washington D.C"
        ];

        async.eachSeries(urlList, loadImg, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          } else {
            console.log("all image are loaded");
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadMaps()">
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What time limit? The Google docs suggest that 49 IMG tags on a page will work. I'm only using three

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20140210073631/https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ 


"The Google Static Maps API has the following usage limits:
50 Static Maps requests per IP address per minute. This means that if you have a single page containing more than 50 maps, the page will exceed this limit." which by implication says a page less than 50 will work, provided it is requested no more than once per minute.

Comment: Do you still get 403 error? If so, let me give your example page url.