# Google Maps Embed API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I get an error "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. An internal error was found for this API project."

I have the maps embed api on.

here is my source

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=10&center=36.8529%2C-75.9780&key={my key}">
```

I created a browser apps key and added "`*.*/*`" as allowed referrer. I have this webpage on an IIS 7 web server on my development machine. I am currently in a university network. Don't know what else to tell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Paras

Comment: According to that error message, it seems you `obfuscated your API key` , not about Embed API, please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934342/what-causes-the-google-maps-api-server-rejected-your-request-an-internal-error) to get some idea.

Comment: all of a sudden it now gives me the following message "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key."

Comment: Try to enabled `Static Maps API` service

Comment: Try `*` as the allowed referrers.

Comment: It worked when I added the IP address of my web server followed by a /* . Now I have a different Issue, It works on a desktop browser but does not work on my iPhone.